# IFCONFIG value is not passed into another variable in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, grep

Here is my piece of code:

```
CONFIG= ifconfig lo;
MAC_ADDRESS="$("${CONFIG}" | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')";
MAC_ADDRESS2="$("${CONFIG}" | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')";

echo "$MAC_ADDRESS" 
echo "$MAC_ADDRESS2"
```

Here I am trying to set `ifconfig lo` into a single variable and try passing into another one where it is needed.

So my expectation is, it should pass like below

```
MAC_ADDRESS="$(ifconfig lo | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')";
MAC_ADDRESS2="$(ifconfig lo | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')";
```

Here I get permission denied exception. Any other possible way to do?

Expected Output:

```
JUKUJSDJDJSJDJSJ
KIIPPSKKSKDKDKKS
```

Comment: Could you please try changing `"${CONFIG}"` to `echo "$CONFIG"` once and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 . The problem is not echo . I need to pass this `CONFIG` into `MAC_ADDRESS`

Comment: Please add sample(not actual addresses) as sample input and sample expected output which you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I have updated the question with sample output. Can u check ?

Comment: Please post sample output of your `ifconfig` command too in post.

Comment: That is passed as an argument ..Updated for your reference.

Comment: first problem the space after `=` split env arguments and runs command, if you really want what you expect use `config=( "ifconfig" "lo" )` and use `"$("${config[@]}" | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')"`

Comment: `"ifconfig lo"` is not a valid command name; you want to run the command `ifconfig` with the argument `lo`. Also, you cannot have a space after the equals sign. (And putting the command in a variable seems superfluous at best, and madness-inducing https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 at worst.)

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul When i try using. Its throwing me an error as `"(" unexpected`

Comment: in bash spaces matter, what have you typed?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul My command is `config=( "ifconfig" "$1" )`

Comment: are you running bash?

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul Yes im running `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @kvantour :  Is there any possible way of doing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**note:** this answer assumes [bash](/questions/tagged/bash). Other shells have different behaviour.

---

If you attempt something similar like this:

```
bash-4.2$ command="ls"
bash-4.2$ $command
bash-4.2$ "$command"
```

Then you will notice that you execute `ls` in both cases. However, if you attempt the following:

```
bash-4.2$ command="ls -l"
bash-4.2$ $command
```

will work as expected (this fails in [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh)), but if you quote it like

```
bash-4.2$ "$command"
bash: ls -l: command not found
```

it fails.

You attempt a similar thing but you have quoted the command in your command-substitution `$(command)`.

In short: **do not**

```
CONFIG= ifconfig lo;
MAC_ADDRESS="$("${CONFIG}" | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')";
```

but **do**

```
CONFIG="ifconfig lo"
MAC_ADDRESS="$(${CONFIG} | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $NF}' | sed -e 's/://g')";
```

<sub>I also fixed your definition of `CONFIG` as it needs <double-quotes> and spaces are not allowed before and after the <equal>-sign (`=`)</sub>

Comment: Works Perfect ! Thanks! Upvote!!! And anything with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772238/print-next-value-compared-string-from-external-source-and-form-a-array